# Document libraries & Office 2016 issue

Tags: 2013, document-library, content-type, office-2016

I have latest version of Office 2016 pro plus installed.

Attempting to save word document to SharePoint 2013 document library that has two document content types.

As of this week. Word no longer prompts user to chose which content type. It does not even save as the default content type.

I have completed some more testing (2/May/18). The issue is certainly SharePoint because when you drag a file into the "+ new document or drag files here" it defaults to the wrong content type.

So how to replicate this issue:

1. SharePoint 2013 Enterprise - Team site collection
2. Create a Team site
3. Create a Content Type and add a site column (for interest sake my site column is a Managed Metadata column) & **make this column mandatory**
4. Add the above CT to the library
5. Set the above CT to default on the library. You should now have your library and the default "Document" CT
6. Drag and drop a file into the library
7. Check file properties, it should be the incorrect CT: "Document"

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check if both the CTs are selected as visible on new form and allow management of CT should be Yes.

Comment: They are, both. Strange thing is , Excel works as expected on the same libraries. At the save dialog in Excel, a popup appears requesting user to select the content type. I'm thinking that this may be a new bug in Word maybe?

Comment: how you saving word documents from word , please check this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/190977f7-ac00-48af-89a3-bcd1c85014e0/save-word-document-directly-into-sharepoint-library?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: File - Save - browse
Type site and library address in address bar at top (or double click shortcut on desktop) or select sharepoint and click on a previously used location.
Save. 
Popup dialog asking to select the content type. Select content type.
OK.
Process has worked hundreds of thousands of times before.

Comment: I've added allot more info on how to replicate the issue. Looks like its definitely a SP issue.

Comment: Can you delete the out of the box Document CT from the library and does that resolve the issue?

Comment: Deleting Document forces the CT to the custom content type.

edit: I've just figured it out. Answer incoming.

Comment: I thought the issue was being caused by properties added to our modified normal template. Turns out its actually not. 

Still working on the issue.